# Modulus of a N number concatenaded N times

Tags: java, algorithm, math, precision, modulo

I had the following scenario today on an Interview for a Developer Job, this was one of the questions, and only one I fail to answer.

Concatenate the number N N times and then calculate his Modulus by 2017.

For example: for N=5 the number will be 55555 and the result will be Mod(55555,2017) = 1096 for N=10 the number will be 10101010101010101010 and the result Mod(10101010101010101010,2017) = 1197

Now the Number I had to calculate was 58184241583791680. The only hint I got was that the result of 58184241583791680 concatenated 58184241583791680 times modulus 2017 is a 4 digit number.

I posted [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1897693/get-the-modulus-of-a-number-n-concatenated-n-times) on math.stackexchange and I got a mathematical approach to this problem, other than brute force.

I wrote the following code in JAVA

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.math.MathContext;

public class Puzzle {
    final static BigInteger M = new BigInteger("2017");

public static void main(String [ ] args) {
    for (long n : new long[] { 1L, 2L, 5L, 10L, 20L }) { 
        System.out.println(n + " --> " + bruteForce(n) + " --- " + formulaV2(n));
    }
}


private static BigInteger bruteForce(long n) {
    String s = "";
    for (long i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        s = s + n;
    }
    return new BigInteger(s.toString()).mod(M);
}

private static BigInteger formulaV2(long n) {
    String aux = String.valueOf(n);
    long L = aux.length();
    long K = n;           

    double op1 = Math.pow(10,L*K);
    BigDecimal minus1 = new BigDecimal(1);
    BigDecimal p1 = new BigDecimal(op1).subtract(minus1);

    double op2 = Math.pow(10,L);
    BigDecimal p2 = new BigDecimal(op2).subtract(minus1).pow(-1,MathContext.DECIMAL64);

    BigDecimal R = new BigDecimal(n).multiply(p1).multiply(p2);
    R = R.setScale(0,BigDecimal.ROUND_UP);
    BigInteger ret = R.toBigInteger();
    return ret.mod(M);
}
}
```

I'm using BigInteger and BigDecimal because I want to get the value of really big numbers (16+ digits).

The bruteForce method will simply concatenate the number inside a loop, and the formulaV2 method will use the formula from the question asked in the math forum.

bruteForce method is just for validation.

However the formula method works well for N<10 but no for N>=10. At N=10 I'm getting incorrect results.

The coding seems to be consistent (to me at least, maybe there is something I'm missing) with the formula provided, and the formula is correct (I checked in Wolfram Alpha).

My guess is that I have precision problems, maybe BigDecimal is not the proper object in this case?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I laid this all out in the comments on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38988665/java-puzzle-whats-the-correct-answer#comment65349106_38988665, but you can take what @Anony-Mousse and others above say and work with it.

One key is to find 10^17 mod 2017 up front. Wolfram Alpha gets that right, anyway at 599, but on other platforms you may need to look at it as ((10^9 mod 2017)*(10^8 mod 2017))mod 2017 to get the 599. You also need that 58184241583791680 mod 2017 is 2005 (again Wolfram gets this right, but lesser platforms may falter if you do not break it up into something like (((581842415 mod 2017)*(10^8 mod 2017) mod 2017)+83791680)mod 2017.

So at each step of the (58184241583791680 but no fear) process you are taking your current number and multiplying it by 10^17 (to move it over to make room for the concatenation) and adding 58184241583791680. But we can do this all mod 2017. In the language of sequences a sub 1 = 2005 and a sub (n+1)=((a sub n)*599+2005) mod 2017.
That is the key step in your for loop. I did the first 4040 or so terms in R (got to love that you can just lay them out on screen interactively and pore over them -- the language is growing on me), though it really would have sufficed to do about half that (the good old Pigeonhole principle at work). And they do not cycle until you actually get all the way out to a sub 2017 which is 2005 again. So is a sub 4033.

In general a sub n = a sub (n mod 2016). You want a sub 58184241583791680. 58184241583791680 mod 2016 is 224 says Wolfram Alpha [again on a lesser platform you may need to break it up into (((581842415 mod 2016)*(10^8 mod 2016) mod 2016)+83791680)mod 2016], so you want a sub 224.

If people want to check themselves or me, I got on R that that was 465. But as was pointed out above, the process is what the question is really interested in.

Comment: Why mod 2016 and not 2017? Because 1646 is taken to 1646 by *599+2005 mod 2017, so it is not in our sequence. Also, I was a little cavalier in my (n mod 2016) above, because in case n=2016, I had not defined a sub 0.

Comment: Great explanation!. Thanks. Got it!.

Answer (score 4):

**Use math!** A good interviewer wants you to use your brain and *solve* a problem, not brute-force things with crappy code.

In this case, he probably wanted you to use the equalities

1. ab mod n = [(a mod n)(b mod n)] mod n
2. (a + b) mod n = [(a mod n) + (b mod n)] mod n

and the fact that e.g. concatenating a four digit number three times is the same as `xyzu * 100010001` and the latter can be further broken down into `10000^0+10000^1+10000^2`.

Now in your case, the base number x and the number of repetitions y is the same, and both are rather big. But the modulus n is small. Let D be the next power of 10 larger than x.

Thus D mod n isn't actually D, but less than 2017. And instead of computing D^y, you can actually compute ((D mod n)^y) mod n, and if you do this in a for loop it will eventually (after at most 2017 steps) *cycle* or become 0. You can therefore compute this term in at most 2017 iterations. So the complexity of this smart approach is O(n) where n is the modulo term, whereas the naive approach will require O(x*y) memory.

With these tricks, you should be able to do this *without* BigInteger, and *much* faster.

Comment: How the for loop will look?, I do not get where the 2017 comes in. The exercise I was given was to concatenate 58184241583791680, 58184241583791680 times and get the modulus by 2017

Comment: Why even loop like that? You can just use a regular `modexp`

Comment: Orejano there are at most 2017 different modulo values. Given that 2017 is prime, we probably need sum(1+2017) plus the first (58184241583791680 mod 2017) iterations. It saves concatenaring 58184241583791680 times! At some point, any additional concatenation then is 0 mod 2017 and we can stop, or we have a cycle (of at most 2016 steps) that we can skip to the very last (partial) pass. @harold modexp does not help, as we need 10^0+10^17+10^34+10^51+... i.e. all interim values, too. So we may as well compute them in a loop as next=(prev*10^17) mod 2017

Comment: @Anony-Mousse the linked answer just uses a couple of modexps

Answer (score 3):

This is a problem:

```
double op1 = Math.pow(10,L*K);
```

for example, when `n = 20`, `L*K = 40`, and `op1 = 10000000000000000303786028427003666890752`. As for why, the usual floating point business: it's the closest it could get. There is no `double` with a value of exactly 1E40.

`op1` won't print like that (you'll see 1E40 and think all is fine), but it will convert like that. Then you're going to use `BigDecimal` which is fine (though odd), it already went wrong before that.

I assume you used `BigDecimal` *because* you converted from a `double`, otherwise you would have used `BigInteger`. Just use `BigInteger.pow` instead of `Math.pow` and it may work (it fixes this issue, if there's anything else I haven't noticed but I can't promise it will work).

`Math.pow(10,L)` on the other hand shouldn't be a problem, because `L` is low enough .. for now. You might as well change that too and have it work for large `L` though.

Comment: Thanks!. I actually changed everything to BigDecimal and now works fine (at least for smalls values).

Comment: @Orejano you can do the entire thing with whole numbers too, in fact you can do it without arbitrary precision math. If you're interested in that it should probably be a new question though

Answer (score 3):

`double op1 = Math.pow(10,L*K)`

This here will overflow for large values of n. Double.MAX_VALUE ~ 1.7*10^308 (i.e.) for L*K > 308, it will overflow.

Edit: double will fail to accurately represent much smaller values as harold mentioned in his answer.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38988665/java-puzzle-whats-the-correct-answer#comment65349106_38988665

Answer (score 0):

You can actually do it in **log(n)** time.
which is faster than any of the methods explained above.

things you would need in your toolbox:

1. **power(a, b)** with some modulo (it would be always right if the modulo is prime which is in your case)
2. knowledge that in **a%x + b%x == (a+b)%x similary for multiplication.**
3. calculating inverse modulo

**if you don't know any of these methods you can google it.**

now to the solution:

first let your given num be 1234
then we need to calculate 1234 1234 1234 ... 1234 times

it is equal to **1234 + 10^4 * 1234 + 10^8 * 1234 + 10^12 * 1234 ... 10^(4* 1233) * 1234**

**we get GP**

== **1234*(10^(4*1234) - 1)/(10^4 - 1)**

replace 1234 with x and 4 (number of digits in N ) with y

we get **x*(10^(x*y) -1 )/(10^y - 1 )**

this power and inverse functions take only log(n) time

now our answer is **x * (power(10, x*y) -1 ) * inverse(power(10, y) - 1)**;
modulo all this and you get your answer

i might have made some mistakes, pardon those.
this might be a heafty read if you don't know the above requirements.

Answer (score -1):

```
import java.math.BigInteger;
class Puzzle {

    final static BigInteger M = new BigInteger("2017");
    private static BigInteger compute(long n) {
         String s = "";
         String a = new BigInteger(n+"").mod(M)+"";

         for (long i = 0; i < Integer.parseInt(a); i++) {
              s = s + a ;
              s = new BigInteger(s).mod(M)+"";
         }
         return new BigInteger(s.toString()).mod(M);

    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {

       for (long n : new long[] { 1L, 2L, 5L, 10L, 20L, 58184241583791680L }) {
           System.out.println("" + n + ": " + compute(n));
       }

    }
}
```